# Windows rt connect to Windows 10 by remote desktop of Windows lagging so bad not because of connection or bandwidth. It is visual that cause it

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, lag, windows-rt

I want to keep this simple as possible.

Problem: connection from Windows rt  8.1 surface rt lagging stuttering delay when scrolling multiple browser in one screen. Not a problem with splashtop and using phone rdp. I can connect easily to my ip address of my computer desktop windows 10.

P.S it is not because of my pc hardware or network connection. Its setting somewhere that i donno and missing.

1. What i have tried, tcp global disable for both computer..
2. Enable at gpedit.msc the encoding letter h.262 something something.
3. Priority realtime

By the way the rdp run at windows rt 8.1 on surface rt with force resolution w1920 h1080 to adjust screen same size as on windows 10 computer.

Windows 10 spec, asus wireless ac88u network adapter, gpu rtx 2070, ryzen 5 2600, m.2 and ssd(windows 10 pro installed)

I think the problem with rdp, cannot run when have alot of gpu rendering, because i think browser also have gpu usage.

Comment: Can you try a different computer than Windows RT ?

Comment: I will try that..

Comment: John, i have confirm for you that my other windows 10 laptop can connect to the same pc windows 10 and it have no problem.. Im aware of the little lag, its just when using rdp in windows rt on surface rt it is worst..

Comment: Windows RT has a different CPU and is not much of a business machine so that is likely the root of your problem.

Comment: But, if im using windows stock remote desktop, the performance is horrible, but when i use remote desktop from store microsoft the performance is better, only the problem is i cannot resize using remote desktop from store.. Smooth performance is using splashtop but splashtop connect too long and macro not functioning using splashtop. I think this surface rt is good enough for remote but maybe outdated windows and app too.. And maybe tweaking some setting in windows or setting encoding.. I just dont have that knowledge..

Comment: Im selling my rt surface.. Close case